# HTML5 flash canva can't stop my sound with "mouseout" function

Tags: javascript, html, flash, createjs, flashcanvas

I found on the Adobe forum an answer to some of my questions about coding MouseOver in "flash html5 mycanva.fla" to trigger a sound when hovering a button. [see here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1595395?start=0&tstart=0)

The thing is, i'm stuck with the "MouseOut function" when it comes to stop the sound played when you MouseOut the button !

The cherry on top would be to pause the sound on mouseout and playit from the point it was paused when mouseover again. But i don't want to appear too greedy ;-)

Here's the code i used in my_flash_canva.fla:

```
var frequency = 3;  
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);  
this.mybutton.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);  

function fl_MouseOverHandler(){  
    playSound("monstres");  
    //linked sound from library by dble clicking on it and named a link in the blank area.Indeed, the action script panel in "mysound" properties panel is greyed..  
    //works like a charm   
}  

this.mybutton.addEventListener("mouseout", fl_MouseOutHandler);  
function fl_MouseOutHandler()  {  
    stopSound("monstres");  
    // doesn't work  
}
```

Using flash pro cc 2014. I guess i must be missing something or bad syntaxing but in my mind what does work with playSound("xxx") should work with stopSound("xxx") . But apparently it 's not that simple. Any clue is welcome, I would be grateful. Thanx a lot.

Olivier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not stop a sound that way. What is `stopSound()`? If you look at your exported HTML, the `playSound` is a function that plays a sound using an ID. It should return an instance that you can control. You have to store that instance, and call `stop()` on it.

```
var sound;
function fl_MouseOverHandler(){  
    sound = playSound("monstres"); 
}  

this.mybutton.addEventListener("mouseout", fl_MouseOutHandler);  
function fl_MouseOutHandler()  {  
    sound.stop(); 
}
```

You will have to modify the generated `playSound` method in the HTML to return the instance that is played, since it currently does not:

```
function playSound(id, loop) {
    return createjs.Sound.play(id, createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_EARLY, 0, 0, loop);
}
```

This is a good thing to report to Adobe, as it should do that already. I have logged a bug to do that.
https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues/218

**[Edit: This fix was included in Adobe Animate]**

Comment: Lanny you're a Lifesaver.

Comment: Thanks. But then, how can you playSound("monstres") if sound with id "monstres" is not preloaded? If I put a sound in the timeline it gets exported and preloaded and then can be also played manually with playSound(). Otherwise you need to preload the sound yourself but there is also the standard preloader for timeline sounds. How to mix the two? Should I put a needed sound manually inside lib.properties.manifest?

Comment: Also: any idea on how to stop a looping sound gracefully? I mean.. stop looping and let it end?